# MOCA Coax-Ethernet kit

Tags: networking, home-networking

Has anyone used the Netgear model or any other soho models?  What are your experiences?  I have FIOS so I was thinking this may come in handy plus all my rooms are wired with coax already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very handy when I need LAN in an A/V rack which already has COAX.

Windows only configuration as far as I know, and make sure your end-points aren't configured as "ALL PASS" which overrides your tv frequencies (if of course you'd still like to use that COAX drop for your cable-tv.)

Much faster than the Ethernet-Over-Powerline option.

Comment: Glad it works well I ordered a Netgear kit for exactly that reason to hook up my HT rack instead of fishing more wire over to it.

Comment: cool let us know how it works out